# Retrieve DLL from directory with Windsor Castle

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I currently have a "PlugInFolder" folder where I want to copy my custom plug-in as DLL Library. 
Every plug-in implements my "IPlugIn" interface.

I want to retrieve them at runtime with Windsor Castle.

I've tried something like this without results:

```
CastleContainer.Instance
       .Install(
        FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("PlugInFolder"))
         );

      CastleContainer.Instance.Register(Component.For<IPlugIn>());


       IPlugIn[] plugIn= CastleContainer.Instance.ResolveAll<IPlugIn>();
```

I receive this error:

```
Type ImageEditorInterfaces.IPlugIn is abstract.
As such, it is not possible to instansiate it as implementation of service ImageEditorInterfaces.IPlugIn.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
container.Register(AllTypes
    .FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("PlugInFolder"))
    .BasedOn<IPlugIn>());
```